# Why isn't my Twitter widget working in my theme?

Tags: twitter

I have Twitter's own widget set to load on my website, which works just fine.
However, on my WP-powered blog the script is included but not rendered. I call it inside an empty `div` like this:

> ```
> <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/twtr-widget.html' ?>
> ```

But it appears in the page source as HTML (I'm putting '...' to save room):

> ```
> <script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script> 
> <script> 
> new TWTR.Widget({...
> ...</script>
> ```

In other words, the script is not being executed. Why is this?

EDIT:
The blog is located [here](http://isaaclubow.com/blog/).

Comment: URL of your site, if possible?

Comment: With the information you provided in your question, it's not easy to say. I smell some javascript error, but that's more guessing than knowing.

Comment: Please see edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say for sure with those floating sidebars, CSS is huge pain to work through.

On the outer layer whole `div` that holds your widget has `display: none;` property applied and there are couple more places with same property applied to parts of twitter widget. Overall this seems like a huge CSS conflict.

Comment: Can confirm the CSS issue from my end. The script gets executed properly.